# Would it be okay to ask a PETSc installation related question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838269/compiling-petsc-on-windows-with-cygwin-okay-to-use-gcc-g-gfortran-as) question on StackOverflow, but it's probably not the right audience, since it has only received 2 views as of my posting this question. I am wondering if it would be okay to ask this on scicomp.SE?

Answer (score 4):

You'd be better off asking this question to the [petsc-users mailing list](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/miscellaneous/mailing-lists.html). Installation questions and many package-specific questions typically get closed with a recommendation to ask the question in a more appropriate forum (usually, a mailing list for that software).